# Detect HDMI connection

Tags: android

How do I detect whether an HDMI cable is plugged or removed from the device? Is there an intent that is send and that I can intercept with Broadcast receivers. Or is there a hidden api to detect the mounting of HDMI? I want to start an activity whenever hdmi is plugged in the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Sony devices you can refer their official blog : [How to use Hidden HDMI API ?](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2012/05/29/how-to-use-the-hidden-hdmi-api-tutorial/)

***Blog says :***
This Sony specific API will be deprecated. Please use the hidden Android intent “android.intent.action.HDMI_PLUGGED” instead. This is supported on smartphones running Ice Cream Sandwich and Jellybean. Stay tuned to Developer World for more information going forward.