# Detect available HDMI source(s) programmatically (PC)?

Tags: c++, c, detect, hdmi

Here on **Stack Overflow**, we have a question like this:

[Detect HDMI connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13176077/2028887)

Unfortunately, it deals with **Android** only. Now, is there any chance of detecting HDMI source on PC, like in C/C++? Are there any platform-specific libraries or something? Both Linux (Ubuntu) and Windows are fine.

Comment: You mean like `video4linux` and `DirectShow`?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Can those libraries be used to perform HDMI output management as well? Like, stream video?

Comment: Those frameworks should be able to handle any video input, processing, and video output for which you have the right drivers.  Audio too.

Comment: @BenVoigt it's `DXVA-HD`
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/dxva-hd .

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин : From the documentation it seems that DXVA is just a processing step and not directly related to a video output.

Comment: @BenVoigt stuff you're talking about is done by video driver

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин The work is done by GPU driver and hardware working together, but controlled by user code building a DirectShow graph.

Comment: @BenVoigt codec can deal with it directly without any graphs.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин: The codec is the implementation of one of the blocks in the graph, but has nothing at all to do with the question.  Codecs are enumerated separately from sources and sinks.  Ultimately your whole thesis is based on faulty logic.  The fact that kernel-mode code CAN do something does not prove that one wanting to do that needs to write a kernel-mode driver.